# jquery ajax to return HTML elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Is it possible to return the entire data and innerhtml of a particular div or I have to follow a different approach .. How can I display the data into the popover div.

The code snippet is below
I am just sending a dummy value as '4' just to check,

**account.php**

In this page I am using a popover to display content processed via ajax

```
<a id="popover" href="#" data-trigger="hover" rel="popover" ><img class="img-thumbnail" src="../xxx/xxx/abc.jpg" width="50"/></a>
<div id="popajax">
</div>
```

jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
    {
        $("#popover").mouseover(function() 
        {
            var textcontent = '4';
            $.ajax({
                    type:'GET',
                    url: "/getuserdetails.php",
                    data: {myval:textcontent},
                    cache: true,
                    error: function(){
                        alert ("ERROR");
                    },
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        $("#popajax").after(html);
                    }  
                });
            return false;

        });
    });
</script>
```

popover script

```
<script>
 $(function () {
$("#popover").popover({  trigger: "hover",
html: true,
 placement : 'top',
  content: function() {
      return $('#popover_content').html();
    },
  title: function() {
      return $('#popover_title').html();
    }
 });
 });
</script>
```

getuserdetails.php

```
<?php   session_start();
include('include/functions.php'); /* This is for crud and other functions*/

    if(isset($_GET['myval']))
    {
    $sql = sql::readOne("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id='$_GET[myval]'");
    }
?>

<div id="popover_title" class="hide" >
          <h4><?php echo $sql[0]->username ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div id="popover_content" class="hide" >

            <div> <p> This is Atul Joshi</p></div>
    </div>
```

*Something Like this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you would like put your result inside `<div id="popajax">
</div>`

You can use `html()` function to insert the element.

```
success: function(data){
    $("#popajax").html(data);
}
```

You can get the html of particular element by using this function. like

```
$(element).html()
```

Or If you want to get inner text of particular element then you can use.

```
$(element).text()
```

Answer (score 1):

To receive html code and display as html text.
You should use `.html()`

```
$('SELECTOR').html('<STRONG>html data</STRONG>');
```

To display it as text, simple `.text()` is enough

```
$('*SELECTOR*').text('your text goes here');
```

Those were for setting values for a selector.

To get html or text from a selector in jquery

Simple `$('SELECTOR').html(); $('SELECTOR').text();` does the work.